# i want to show duplicate value error on front end

Tags: django, python-3.x

i have an query_name field in database. i want that every value should be unique so i changed it constraint and add unique= true.
now i want that if user enter the duplicate value then error duplicate value show to the user. currently error is showing only in backend

here is my code in python

```
def save_report(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST.dict())
        data_dict = request.POST.dict()
        query_json = {}
        #query json data
        query_json['data_src_name'] = data_dict['data_src_name']
        query_json['fields']        = data_dict['fields']
        query_json['group_by']      = data_dict['group_by']
        query_json['order_by']      = data_dict['order_by']
        query_json['where']         = data_dict['where']
        query_json['limit']         = data_dict['limit']
        query_json                  = json.dumps(query_json)
        report_creation_obj = ReportCreationData.objects.create(
                            query_json       = query_json, 
                            data_source_name = data_dict['data_src_name'], 
                            query_name       = data_dict['query_name'], 
                            mail_body        = data_dict['mail_body'])

        report_creation_obj.save()

        return HttpResponse('success')

    else:
        return render(request, 'home/report_creation.html', context = None)

database :

query_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique= True, default= True)
```

code 2 :

```
def save_report(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST.dict())

        querydata = ReportCreationData.objects.all()
        querydata_list = []
        querydata_dict = {'query_name':''}
        for data in querydata:
            querydata_dict['query_name'] = data.query_name
            print ('querydata_dict', querydata_dict)



        data_dict  = request.POST.dict()
        query_name = data_dict['query_name'],
        print ('query_name', query_name)

        query_json = {}
        #query json data
        query_json['data_src_name'] = data_dict['data_src_name']
        query_json['fields']        = data_dict['fields']
        query_json['group_by']      = data_dict['group_by']
        query_json['order_by']      = data_dict['order_by']
        query_json['where']         = data_dict['where']
        query_json['limit']         = data_dict['limit']
        query_json                  = json.dumps(query_json)


        report_creation_obj = ReportCreationData.objects.create(
                            query_json       = query_json, 
                            data_source_name = data_dict['data_src_name'], 
                            query_name       = data_dict['query_name'], 
                            mail_body        = data_dict['mail_body'])



        if (query_name == querydata_dict).exists():

            raise ('already exists')

        else:
            report_creation_obj.save()

        return HttpResponse('success')
    else:
       return render(request, 'home/report_creation.html')

with code 2 getting error:
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'exists'
```

Please help

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

You can try before inserting the data,run a select query from database and apply where clause on your **query_name** with your current value.So by this you can get duplicate records.